# mysql between show matched value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns showing ranges, like

```
id    from     to
1     10       100
2     200      300
```

I have a query which will be a list of values, like 17, 20, 44, 288 etc.

Is it possible to have a result set which would include the where condition, so I get:

```
id    from     to    input
1     10       100   7
1     10       100   20
1     10       100   144
2     200      300   288
```

Right now the code runs one query per where value and it works, and I'm looking to increase performance by combing it into one large multiple where clause, like

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE (from<=7 AND start>=7) 
    OR (from<=20 AND start>=20) 
    OR (from<=144 AND start>=144) 
    OR (from<=288 AND start>=288)
```

Comment: After re-reading this, I'm thinking of changing the sql to retrieve least max value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want makes no sense regarding ranges.

`7` and `144` has no compatible range yet you want to put then into the first range.

In a result set with lots of values listing you will probably get to many conditions.

What you can do is to put those values that isn't in a range to show without correspondence. Like this:

With the structure being:

```
create table test (
   id integer,
   vfrom integer,
   vto integer  
);

insert into test values
(1, 10, 100),
(2, 200, 300);

create table vals(
val integer
);

insert into vals values (7), (20), (144), (288);
```

You can use this query:

```
select val, id, vfrom, vto
  from vals v left join
       test t on ( t.vfrom <= v.val and t.vto >= v.val )
```

It will bring you:

```
7     null null null
20     1    10   100
144   null null null
288    2    200  300
```

see it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f68fd/8

Maybe it isn't what you want but it is more logical.

Comment: Yes that was best. I saved to a table, and then offloaded all processing to the data layer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is a query for this. Trouble is we need a table for specific values to show up; and then there are sub-queries and union selects:

```
SELECT table.*, values.val AS input
  FROM (SELECT 7 AS val UNION SELECT 20 AS val UNION SELECT 144 AS val UNION SELECT 288 AS val) as values
  JOIN table ON table.from <= values.val AND table.to >= values.val
```

This should do the trick. Note that you only have to specify the column name in the first `SELECT` with in a `UNION SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose you are using Java as your application language. You could build your query this way:

```
public String buildQuery(int[] myList) {
    String queryToReturn = "";
    for (int queryIndex = 0; queryIndex < myList.length; queryIndex++) {
        queryToReturn += ((queryIndex == 0) ? ("") : (" union ")) + 
        "(select `id`, `from`, `to`, " + myList[queryIndex] + " as input 
          from MyTable 
          where `from` < " + myList[queryIndex] + " and " + myList[queryIndex] " < `to`)";
    }
    return queryToReturn;
}
```

Then run the returned query.